# The number of different G-actions on X

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $X$ $=$ $\{$$1$, $2$, $3$$\}$ and $G$ $=$ $\mathbb Z_2$. How many different G-actions are there on $X$?

Just learned group action. Need some hint on this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: prove any such group action either does nothing or has the nontrivial group element switch two things (and leave the third fixed).

With more algebra: a group action will be a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\to S_3$, which will be determined by where it sends the nontrivial element, which must be taken to either the identity or an element of order two. You can list out all the elements of $S_3$ and identify the elements of order two.

Comment: So we have identity, (12), (23), or (13), that is four different G-actions?

Comment: Correct. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if $G$= $\mathbb Z_3$, there will be 3! G-actions. What if $G$ = $\mathbb Z_4$?

Comment: No, there will not be $3!=6$ actions of $\Bbb Z_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$. What makes you think that?

Comment: Oh so for $\mathbb Z_3$ we do not have the elements that have order 2 in it so we dont count those that switch only 2 elements in $S_3$?

Comment: Here's what you need to know: If $C$ is a cyclic group generated by $c$ (which means it's either $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_n$ for some $n$), and $G$ is any other group, then any homomorphism $C\to G$ is uniquely determined by where it sends $c$. Conversely, one can find a homomorphism that sends $c$ to any element of $G$ whose order divides $c$'s order in $C$. All of these things can (and should be) proven in intro abstract algebra / group theory courses, usually *before* discussing group actions. Thus actions of $C$ on $X$ are in correspondence with permutations of $X$ whose order divides $|C|$.